# trying to stub a char value with ocmock

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

I have a note class with the following:

```
@interface Note
    -(char)alphabetName;
@end
```

And I am trying to stub this out in a test:

```
id mockNote = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[Note class]];
[[[mockNote stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE((char){'A'})] alphabetName];
```

And my test suite will not run due to getting an error on the stub call:  "Taking the address of a temporary object of type 'char'"

Comment: I pasted your code into a test and it runs fine, with no errors. What version of OCMock are you using?

Comment: where does one find the version number?  It's not anywhere in the source code (that I can see at least)..  I added OCMock to my project in September...  I am still having this error happen:  http://tinyurl.com/9bgmgbw

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this error. What happens if you get rid of the temporary?

```
id mockNote = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[Note class]];
char a = 'A';
[[[mockNote stub] andReturnValue:OCMOCK_VALUE(&a)] alphabetName];
```

Comment: then it works fine..  But, that's kind of annoying to have to do.